# Page losing formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my page a I have a few textboxes, AJAX tabpanel and a gridview.

In the `Page_Load` event, textboxes are filled in; gridview is populated and so on.

My gridview has a button:

```
<Columns>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRedirect"
         Text="Click me"
         CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BkId_ZW")%>'
         OnClick="DoRedirect"
         runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
...
</Columns>
```

and the code behind it looks like:

```
    protected void DoRedirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button theButton = sender as Button;
        string url ="http://../profile/" + theButton.CommandArgument;
        Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + url + "');</script>");           
    }
```

After button is pressed a new window is open (everything works as expected) but the main page loose values and formatting of the textboxes.

What is going on? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Write()` is not favored for this purpose. Since you are adding to the response in the middle of the ASP.net page lifecycle, you are changing the page output. If you view source, you might find your `<script>window.open...</script>` line in some awkward place.

Therefore, use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript()` instead.

Comment: Thank you David for fast reply but can you give me an example how to use it?

Comment: Don’t worry @David, I’ve managed to work it out. 
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(theButton, this.GetType(), "JSCR", "<script>window.open('" + url + "');</script>", false);`

Thank you again.